# javascript callback clarification

Tags: javascript, callback

I know there is a lot of info out there on callbacks, but I am still struggling a little to grasp it.  I wrote the following code just trying to see if I could understand the flow of callbacks and feel like I am close, but am still missing something:

```
var sum = function(a, b){
  return a + b;
};

var times = function(x, y){
  return x * y;
};

var math = function(sum, times, callback){
  console.log(sum + times);
  callback(times);
};

math((1,2),(3,3), function(totalizer){
  console.log(totalizer);
});
```

this logs 5 and 3 to the console(which seems to be the last two values(2 +3) and the last value in the times(3), when I'd like it to return 12 9.  If you see the issue please let me know, I appreciate the help.  Also, any info you have to help clarify what I'm doing wrong would be great.

thanks

Comment: I have no idea what `(1,2)` means.  In console if you execute it, you get `2`.  You can also execute `1,2` (without the parenthesis).  I still have no idea what that syntax means. Edit: ok that makes sense now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator.  It wasn't registering for me because I'm not used to it being in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a callback function is to be able to call a function within another function. Let's take a look at your code:

```
// A function called `sum` that takes two parameters
var sum = function(a, b){
  return a + b;
};

// A function called `times` that takes two parameters
var times = function(x, y){
  return x * y;
};

// A function called `math` that takes three parameters
var math = function(sum, times, callback){
  console.log(sum + times);
  callback(times);
};
```

So you've defined three functions, looks good so far, let's continue:

```
math((1,2),(3,3), function(totalizer){
  console.log(totalizer);
});
```

So it looks like you're trying to call your `math` function from before and (correct me if I'm wrong) it looks like you want the arguments to be so:

```
math(the sum of 1 and 2, the product of 3 and 3, a function that will print its argument){
   ...
}
```

So in order to do this, you need to *use* the functions you've defined from earlier. Consider something like this:

```
math(sum(1,2), times(3,3), function(totalizer){
  console.log(totalizer);
});
```

So now, we're executing the `math` function with the parameters `sum(1, 2)`, `times(3, 3)`, and some callback function. So now let's look at what happens next:

```
// Your math function:
function(sum, times, callback){
  // This will log your sum + time arguments
  // will log `12`
  console.log(sum + times);

  // Now your callback function from earlier will be executed
  // using `times`
  callback(times);
};
```

So we go back to the callback you passed in earlier:

```
function(totalizer){
  console.log(totalizer);
});
```

And that executes with `times` as your parameter (will log `9`).

This may have been a little long winded, but hopefully this helps you grasp a better understanding of callbacks and how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `sum` or `times` function even once. `The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand. (MDC)` (https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)

What you tried to do is probably this:

```
math(sum(1,2),times(3,3), function(totalizer){
  console.log(totalizer);
});
```

This will log 12 and 9 as you had expected.

Edit to answer your comment:

You are mixing up variable names and function names:

```
var math = function(sum, times, callback){
  console.log(sum + times);
  callback(times);
};
```

is exactly the same as

```
var math = function(foo, bar, callback){
  console.log(foo + bar);
  callback(bar);
};
```

If you try to search for `javascript variable scope`or something similar, you'll probably find a lot of posts that clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks, Jack, this makes sense.  Why do I have to add the sum and times variable names though, since they are in the original math function?